# until+Subject+Verb(simple present tense) and until+Ving

Tags: grammar

The reduced form of "I do something until I get somewhere" is "I do something until getting somewhere"?
If it is yes, is the sentence structure, "until+Ving", of latter one a commom and natural usage?

Thanks for your time:)

Comment: Can you make a more concrete example, not just using something and somewhere?

Comment: I would've said, "I do things until I get what I want".